# Does the following have a nice combinatorial closed form?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I am wondering if the function has a 'nice' closed form.

The function is $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n {r \choose i}{q \choose n-i}x^i $$ where $n,q \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$  and $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and I'm happy to assume $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ if this is needed. To give an idea of what I'm looking for, note that $$f(1)= {r+q \choose n}$$ by Vandermonde's identity. The reason I care about this is that I am trying to estimate its $p$-adic valuation and having a closed form would be great.

Comment: $f$ is a polynomial. That's pretty nice. We also know that $$\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{r+1}\left[\binom{r+q+1}{n+1}-\binom{q}{n+1}\right]$$